# Making a visual grid on a Frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm tring to create 3 Frames (right, center, left) in the root in tkinter 8.6
and then making a visual grid ( using "-") in each frame. I get the following error message when I try to make the grid on the first panel.

> TypeError: grid_configure() takes at least 1 argument (0 given).

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1366x768")      


frame_right = Frame(root,width = 1366/4,height = 768bg = "powder blue")
frame_right.pack(side = LEFT)

frame_center = Frame(root,width = 1366/2,height = 768,bg = "red")
frame_center.pack(side = LEFT)

frame_left = Frame(root,width = 1366/4,height = 768,bg = "steel blue")
frame_center.pack(side = LEFT)

for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,20):

        Label(frame_left,text = "-",width = 10,height = 1)
        Label.grid(row = i,column = j)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Label(parent, {some arguments})`, you create an instance on the first line, on the second you create an instance with no parent.

Must be change:

```
Label(frame_left,text = "-",width = 10,height = 1)
Label.grid(row = i,column = j)
```

to:

```
label = Label(frame_left,text = "-",width = 10,height = 1)
label.grid(row = i,column = j)
```

or:

```
Label(frame_left,text = "-",width = 10,height = 1).grid(row = i,column = j)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar I use in my code to add visible spacing on my main row and column.

I don't think you need to define height because the text will do that for you.

You might want to try using something like this.

```
for col_num in range(20):
    spacer=Label(root, text=str(col_num)) 
        #replace root with your frame
        #you can replace str(col_num) with your "-"
    spacer.grid(row = 0, column = col_num)
    root.columnconfigure(col_num, minsize=10)
for row_num in range(10):
    spacer=Label(root, text=str(row_num)) #replace root with your frame
    spacer.grid(row = row_num, column = 0)
    root.rowconfigure(row_num, minsize=10)
```